# Characteristics of Pressure - Fluid Mechanics

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics, free-body-diagram

1. What does it mean when without flow, the pressure must be transmitted normal to solid boundaries and arbitrary surfaces in a fluid?
2. Also, the pressure at a point is the same regardless of orientation of the area upon which it acts?

Answer (score 1):

In a static situation, fluid pressure on a solid surface is caused by molecules of the fluid bouncing off the surface.  When averaged over billions of collisions, the components of impact parallel to the surface give a resultant of zero. That result is independent of the orientation of the surface.